# Hosting Angular 6 application to firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, hosting, firebase-hosting

I am trying to hosting Angular 6 application in firebase. Aftter making a project in firebase , i followed the every step in firebase hosting documentation.

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/vision-api-20789/hosting/main

after firebase deploy command i got the 2 urls

[image]

but when i go to hosting Url it is redirected to firebase hosting documentaion page.not redirected to my application.

Comment: check your dist folder, does it contain all of your angular project files?
Or does it contain a folder called: out-tsc ?
If so you need to change the output of the build to output to dist

Comment: Angular 6 changed from building to `dist` to building to `dist/<app-name>`. You probably need to change the firebase config for public directory to `dist/<app-name>` replacing `<app-name>` with the name of the Angular app.

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that in angular 6 the project files aren't output to the dist folder, in your tsconfig.json change:

```
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
```

to:

```
"outDir": "./dist",
```